# Custom A star crashes unity when enabling raycasts for walls in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, a-star

I decided to make my own A*. When I enable this part of the code Unity crashes.

```
if (Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, a - new Vector2(current.x, current.y), 1, mask))
{
    print(i);
    continue;
}
```

There are no other objects than walls that would enable the Raycast.
The code probably enters an infinite loop, but I have no idea how because it works fine if i disable raycasts.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class Star : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int x, y;
    private int nextX, nextY;

    public Vector2 targetNode;
    private Vector2 nextNode;
    private List<Node> path = null;

    LayerMask mask;
    Bounds area;

    private bool moving;
    private bool check;

    public float timeStart;
    public Vector3 startPos;
    public float speed = 1f;

    float u;
    Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        mask = LayerMask.GetMask("Default");
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!moving)
        {
            Move();
        }
        else
            MoveTo(speed);
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        area = new Bounds(transform.position, new Vector3(100, 100));
        int playerX = (int)Mathf.Round(Player.x);
        int playerY = (int)Mathf.Round(Player.y);
        Vector2 start = new Vector2((int)transform.position.x, (int)transform.position.y);
        Vector2 destination = new Vector2(playerX, playerY);

        if (getDistance(start, destination) > 1f)
            path = findPath(start, destination);
        else
            path = null;

        nextX = 0;
        nextY = 0;
        if (path != null)
        {
            if (path.Count > 0)
            {
                nextNode = new Vector2(path[path.Count - 1].x, path[path.Count - 1].y);
                if (x < nextNode.x) nextX++;
                if (x > nextNode.x) nextX--;
                if (y < nextNode.y) nextY++;
                if (y > nextNode.y) nextY--;
            }
        }
        if (nextX != 0 || nextY != 0)
        {
            Move(nextX, nextY);
        }
    }

    public List<Node> findPath(Vector2 start, Vector2 goal)
    {
        x = (int)start.x;
        y = (int)start.y;
        List<Node> openList = new List<Node>();
        List<Node> closedList = new List<Node>();
        Node current = new Node(x, y, null, 0, getDistance(start, goal));
        openList.Add(current);
        while (openList.Count > 0)
        {
            openList.Sort();
            current = openList[0];
            if (new Vector2(current.x, current.y).Equals(goal))
            {
                List<Node> path = new List<Node>();
                while (current.parent != null)
                {
                    path.Add(current);
                    current = current.parent;
                }
                openList.Clear();
                closedList.Clear();
                return path;
            }
            openList.Remove(current);
            closedList.Add(current);
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                if (i == 4/* || i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 6 || i == 8*/) continue;
                int x = current.x;
                int y = current.y;
                int xi = (i % 3) - 1; // -1, 0, 1
                int yi = (i / 3) - 1;
                Vector2 a = new Vector2(x + xi, y + yi);
                if (Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, a - new Vector2(current.x, current.y), 1, mask))
                {
                    print(i);
                    continue;
                }
                double gCost = current.gCost + (getDistance(new Vector2(current.x, current.y), a));
                double hCost = getDistance(a, goal);
                Node node = new Node((int)a.x, (int)a.y, current, gCost, hCost); // store the node
                if (!vecInList(openList, a)) openList.Add(node);
            }
        }
        closedList.Clear();
        return null;
    }

    private double getDistance(Vector2 tile, Vector2 goal)
    {
        int dx = (int)(tile.x - goal.x);
        int dy = (int)(tile.y - goal.y);
        return Mathf.Sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));
    }

    private bool vecInList(List<Node> list, Vector2 vector)
    {
        foreach (Node n in list)
        {
            Vector2 tile2 = new Vector2(n.x, n.y);
            if (tile2.Equals(vector)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void Move(int x, int y)
    {
        targetNode = transform.position + new Vector3(x, y);
        if (area.Contains(new Vector3(Player.x, Player.y)) && (moving == false))
        {
            moving = true;
            check = true;
        }
    }

    public void MoveTo(float speed)
    {
        if (check)
        {
            check = false;
            moving = true;
            timeStart = Time.time;
            startPos = transform.position;
        }

        if (moving)
        {
            u = (Time.time - timeStart) / (1 / speed);
            if (u >= 1)
            {
                u = 1;
                moving = false;
            }
            //transform.position = (1 - u) * (Vector2)startPos + u * targetNode;
            rb.MovePosition((1 - u) * (Vector2)startPos + u * targetNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: got this to work thanks to Yuri's comment. Changed to:

```
if (Physics2D.Raycast(new Vector2(current.x, current.y), a - new Vector2(current.x, current.y), 1, mask))
```

I was checking from the start position instead of the last position in the nodes.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are there any log outputs or error messages? If so, please include them in your question

Comment: Explain crashing, does it just hang being unresponsive, does it crash immediately, does it give any error messages before crashing, is it the entirety of Unity that crashes or just your application? Does your Unity [log files](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html) contain any information about the crash?

Comment: There were no error messages. The log outputs end by printing the i of the direction of the wall. Unity hangs unresponsive and has to be stopped with task manager

Comment: Try `Physics2D.Raycast(new Vector2(current.x, current.y), a - new Vector2(current.x, current.y), 1, mask)` can't check now but looks like the problem. Anyway, this algorithm has a problem - it will never stop if there is no path to destination and it is not bound by the walls from all directions.

Comment: I'm so glad I got this to work. Yuri Nudelman's solution worked. Thank you so much everyone